# How to use a specific version of virtualenvwrapper when multiple exist?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenvwrapper

I am new to Python, so I was just trying to set my Linux Mint up for some Python development. I saw a lot of answers here on SO advising me against touching the pre-existing Python module, which is Python2.7. Hence, I installed Python3.7 separately. When it came to installing `virtualenvwrapper`, I installed it using the following command

```
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

Following some other article however, I think I installed another version of `virtualenvwrapper` with the help of Python3.7 using the following command

```
python3.7 -m pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

Now there exist two different versions of `virtualenvwrapper` and I know this because when I run the following

```
pip list |  grep virtualenvwrapper
```

I get `virtualenvwrapper 4.3.1`

But when I run the following

```
python3.7 -m pip list | grep virtualenvwrapper
```

I get `virtualenvwrapper 4.8.2`

Now I am confused as to which one to use. I don't even know if there's any point of keeping two versions of the same thing. I don't know how to remove the `virtualenvwrapper 4.3.1`. I would like to use the one I installed using Python3.7, but not sure how to do that.

Please let me know if

1. Removing `virtualenvwrapper 4.3.1` will break anything
2. If no is the answer to the question above, how do I remove that specific version of `virtualenvwrapper`
3. How to make use of the `virtualenvwrapper` installed using Python3.7

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Python!

You're traveling along the common axis of Python 2 vs Python 3.  It's a future forward choice to begin your development using Python 3.

1. Removing virtualenvwrapper 4.3.1 will not break anything, especially if you haven't begun using it as part of your development workflow.
2. & 3. In Linux Mint, Python 2 and Python 3 are completely independent installations.  So typically removing a package from one won't affect the other.  virtualenvwrapper is a bit of an exception though, because it's more than a Python package - it's a sort of shell extension and it installs to `/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`.  I would suggest first running `pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper` to remove the 2.7 installation and then re-running `python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade --force-install virtualenvwrapper` to ensure the 3.7 one is good.  This should leave virtualenvwrapper from 3.7 as the sole survivor and Python 3.7 as the one it uses by default.

As you're just starting into Python development, may I suggest a different path: may I suggest using https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, "an elegant weapon for a more civilized age".  It streamlines the management of virtual environments and packages.  While I started with virtualenvwrapper seven years ago, I've been using pipenv for the last year and loving it.  `python3.7 -m pip install pipenv` will get you started in Linux Mint.